# How can I pass string from recycleView adapter to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass a string from adapter to fragment and move to this fragment when I click on an image 
but it's not worked

in my adapter

```
        holder.imageProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ProfileFragment.class);
                intent.putExtra("publisherId", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

in fragment in "onCreateView"

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String profileId=intent.getStringExtra("publisherId");
```

how can I do that?

Comment: `mContext.startActivity(intent);`. startActivity does exactly this, it starts an activity, not a fragment

Comment: but the fragment work when I run the code before adding  " Intent intent = getIntent();"
in the fragment..
the problem start when I tried to pass a string ...
if you know how can I do that without intent please tell me.
@a_local_nobody

Comment: Is the ProfileFragment current fragment where you set the recyclerView? And want to pass the string from adapter to profileFragment onClick of the imageProfile?

Comment: @MittalVarsani  no, not the current fragment.
this recycle view is represent a Post.. I'm trying to build a simple social app..
the Post is in Home Fragment.. what I wanted is to pass the publisher Id from Home Fragment to Profile Fragment when I clicked on the post Publisher image

Comment: @rubatala  what is datatype of `post.getPublisher()` ?

Comment: @DeepParsania string

Comment: @rubatala `ProfileFragment` is Fragment or Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your adapter

```
     holder.imageProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                     Fragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("publisherId", post.getPublisher()); //key and value
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_containar, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

in fragment in "onCreate"

```
String profileId = getArguments().getString("publisherId");
```